# Passport req.isAuthenticated() doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express, session, authentication, passport.js

I'm using express-session and passport to authenticate.
Here's my module :

(updated)

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
        LamAdmin.findOne({ email: username }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username' }); }
            if (!comparePassword(user.password, password)) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password' }); }
            return done(null, user);
        });
  }
));

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local',{
    successRedirect: '/p/dashboard',
    failureRedirect: '/p',
    failureFlash: true
}));


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  LamAdmin.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

function checkAuth(req,res,next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/p');
    }
}

// //DOES NOT WORK WITH CHECKAUTH MIDDLEWARE
// router.get('/dashboard',(req,res,next)=> {
//      res.render('dashboard');
// });

router.get('/dashboard',checkAuth,(req,res,next)=> {
        res.render('dashboard');
});
```

checkAuth is my middleware and idk why it always returns false.
This is passport and session configs in app.js :

```
//sessions
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  cookie: { secure: false } // Remember to set this
}));

//passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Is there anything wrong with my checkAuth middleware ?

Or my redirect to Dashboard view?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's probably because you haven't defined the authentication strategy and serialization/deserialization logic.

Comment: @SwatiAnand How should i make it correct exactly?

Answer (score 0):

When you call passport.authenticate() method, it uses a strategy to authenticate the user. If you have the user information stored in a local DB, then you can use the Local Strategy that will use username and password to authenticate. So in your app.js add the following:

```js
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    /* Change this to fetch user info from your db
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      if (!comparePasswords(user.password, password)) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user);
    }); 
    */
  }
));
```

When the user is authenticated, serializeUser() method is called with the user object returned from the above method passed as an argument and express appends the value returned to the current user session in req.session.passport.user

```js
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});
```

On each subsequent request, when isAuthenticated() method is called, passport checks if some value is present in req.session.passport.user. If user information is present, it calls the deserializeUser() method which appends the user information to the request and can be accessed via req.user

```js
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  // Replace it with your db
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Comment: I've updated my module, i tried your code but it's not working when I use 'checkAuth' middleware when redirect to 'dashboard'